# should I use stream to get big data from mySQL?

Tags: node.js, bigdata, streaming, child-process, nodejs-stream

so I have to get big data which is approximately 1017208 KB from MySQL. The problem is that it takes time when I retrieve it . After some googling, I find out I can use stream or child processer to improve the performance.

I'm using the data to draw a graph

my backend is Nodejs
my frontend is Reactjs

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.